# Modulus(%) operator in Typescript not working correctly for big numbers

Tags: typescript, operators, modulus, modulo

I'm writing a specific validator and needed the modulus of a 16 digit number. Noticed that the operator % doesn't work correctly after 15 digits. I can rewrite my code to check less digits, but I could not find this limitation anywhere in the documentation. What is the reason for this working badly?

Tried checking these values in a normal .ts file:

```
console.log(10000000000000000%97); 

console.log(10000000000000001%97);

console.log(10000000000000002%97);

console.log(10000000000000003%97);

console.log(10000000000000004%97);
```

Expected result when using a the regular calculator is:

```
62
63
64
65
66
```

On the other hand, the output was:

```
62
62
64
66
66
```

Answer (score 9):

You are running into the quirks of floating point representation. Numbers in JavaScript are represented using the [floating point standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). This standard makes tradeoffs between range and precision. The larger the number the less precision you have. This means that really large numbers can't be represented accurately. For example `10000000000000001` can't be represented in this standard, so you actually end up with `10000000000000000`. You can test this out if you `console.log` the numbers:

```
console.log(10000000000000000);
console.log(10000000000000001);
console.log(10000000000000002);
console.log(10000000000000003);
console.log(10000000000000004);
```

Output is:

```
10000000000000000
10000000000000000
10000000000000002
10000000000000004
10000000000000004
```

If you want to represent large numbers with greater precision you will need to use a custom large number library ([ex](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)). There is also [proposed bigint support](https://v8.dev/features/bigint) in Javascript, but at least at time of writing this has limited support in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Javascript problem, not Typescript. The maximum safe integer in Javascript is 2^53 - 1, you can check here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number

You can use BigInt if you want to work with numbers that big, you can represent them adding an n at the end of the number. If you try this:

```
console.log(10000000000000000n%97n);

console.log(10000000000000001n%97n);

console.log(10000000000000002n%97n);

console.log(10000000000000003n%97n);

console.log(10000000000000004n%97n);
```

It should do what you expect.

Edit: as mentioned above BigInt is not supported by some browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=bigint